# What can get destroyed in your settlements?

Tags: fallout-4

So far, nothing in my settlement (I favour the Starlight Drive-In) has been destroyed, but I've heard mention ([in this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242752/what-are-the-consequences-of-settlements-getting-attacked)) of things getting destroyed in a settlement during an attack. Is there a list of those vulnerable objects? Is it limited to "items" like generators and people, or can walls and other "building" structures be destroyed?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a comprehensive list, but so far the only things I've had destroyed are defenses and resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As discussed in this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242752/52800), it's not so much "destroyed" as it is "damaged to 0 durability". It seems that this damage is limited to defences (guard towers and turrets) along with resource generation (crops, water pumps, generators).

Comment: Good to know my rickety, wooden skyscraper won't collapse due to attack! ;)