# What happens if I really don't like one of my settlements and refuse to defend it?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm really not a fan of Tenpines Bluff.  Those two citizens need to suck it up and learn to deal with raiders themselves if they won't move to one of my more well defended settlements.  Their settlement has no defenses and I refuse to build any, so what happens if they get attacked by raiders and I just stand by and laugh instead of rushing to their aid?

Comment: They will possibly get killed and that is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As discussed here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242752/52800), if you don't defend your settlements the attackers will potentially kill the settlers present at that settlement (assuming the settlers are themselves unable to repel the attackers) and [damage certain properties](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243864/52800), for example seems that this  defences (guard towers and turrets) and resource generators (crops, water pumps, generators).

Answer (score 0):

You could send both of the settlers to another settlement (assuming the rest aren't maxed in population) and then dismantle/turn-off the radio. Then no new settlers will arrive, and the raiders can do what they like w/out any negative consequences for you what-so-ever.

Comment: Some settlers won't move

Comment: Then they will die to raiders eventually, if they aren't considered **Essential** by the game.

Comment: I specifically used Tenpines as an example since those settlers won't move.  This probably means that they are considered Essential by the game and won't die either, though.

Comment: @RESPAWN Well, if you already don't care what happens to them why don't you try killing them to find out?

Comment: @Iszi I'm afraid that Codsworth wouldn't like that. ;)

Comment: @RESPAWN So? Dismiss him first. Or save/reload. :-P